# Necessary for a portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

Receiving orders for work from clients and assign them to freelancers. But, I am not from IT business but administration.

Comment: Hi Omaruko, welcome to Freelancing.SE! I am having a hard time understanding what your question is that you are asking. Can you [edit] to clearly mark a *question* you need answered? For more information, please refer to [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As admin, it is unlikely that you will have a portfolio. Instead, you should create a solid CV and present this when asked for details about previous work.

In addition, speak to your current/previous employers and ask if they would be happy to write you a reference, or a recommendation on linkedin.

Comment: Thank you for reaching me out.
The reason why I have asked you for the following reason.

1.I would not make a permanent contract prospective clients.
  Therefore, the portfolio is preferable than CV, I think.
2.Here is the example of the portfolio , which is the person who has not related the web, or rather he/she is an admin.

Awaiting　for your further comments or suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the URL.
https://workshift-sol.com/users/view/15354

Answer (score 0):

A portfolio can give you an idea of the quality and style of a freelance designer. witch can be a helpful tool to made decisions (witch work, witch frelancer).  But if you don't have a background or experience in design it will be pretty useless.

I never find much use in a portfolio from a developer/programer because a portfolio is more visual and development have many relevant background aspects that a portfolio can show.

Comment: Thank you for reaching me out.
Please refer to my comment as I have replied for Mr. John HC.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get reference letters from previous customers/clients I would add to your portfolio page  words such as 
" On specific request, if required during negotiations, we can present letters of recommendation from past and present clients."

PS what is "&amp" mistype in the English text.

Comment: I doubt why reference letters have anything to do with my question.Your reply is off the point.